# Can't install Windows 7: not a valid Win32 application

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I Have a Windows 7 disk but it won't automatically install.

I get the same window over and over, saying it isn't a valid Win32 application. I can't boot from it, either.

I have a Gateway GT5238e with Core 2 Duo 2.13GHz processor, running Windows XP MCE, 3 GB RAM, 320 GB HDD, ATI Radeon HD 3650. Autoplay doesn't work, I get the same errors. Any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to boot to CD, and what error are you getting? Or are you trying to install from within windows? Is your disk a 64bit OS?

Comment: yes i am trying to boot to CD. i'm getting a not compatible with this version of windows error massage.i did try to install from within windows and the error message is not a valid win32 application. yes it is a 64bit disk. i just used it last week to reload an almost new laptop.

Comment: are you trying to upgrade install or clean install?

Comment: "Boot CD" means to start up the computer from a powered-off state with the CD in the drive, executing the code on the CD.... your terminology implies you're trying to start the CD from within Windows.   THAT won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to upgrade 32-bit Windows XP to 64-bit Windows 7 you can only do it by booting from the DVD and replacing the Windows XP installation. You will not be able to perform an in-place upgrade.

You need to check in your BIOS to ensure that you have Boot From Optical Drive enabled and/or that the Optical Drive is before the HDD in the boot priority.

BIOS settings can vary greatly so it will be difficult for anyone who doesn't have the same PC  to tell you what they are for your PC.

A very good guide to BIOS settings and what they mean is here: http://www.techarp.com/freebog.aspx

Comment: ok thank you. i'll check that out and get back to you